STM32F446 SPI DMA
I am using SPI1 DMA for sending data from STM32F446RET6 to Nokia5110 LCD. But it doesn't work. When I try without DMA, it works. Is my program wrong? Full program can be downloaded via the following link. It can be opened with STM32 Cube IDE. https://easyupload.io/m78pr9
static void initSPI1(void)
{
    // PA5, PA6, PA7 AS AF7
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= 1<<0;
    GPIOA->MODER &= ~(1<<10 | 1<<12 | 1<<14);
    GPIOA->MODER |= 1<<11 | 1<<13 | 1<<15;
    GPIOA->AFR[0] |= 1<<20 | 1<<22 | 1<<24 | 1<<26 | 1<<28 | 1<<30;

    // SPI1 CONFIG
    RCC->APB2ENR |= 1<<12;
    SPI1->CR1 |= 1<<2 | 1<<3 | 1<<4 | 1<<5 | 1<<8 | 1<<9;
    SPI1->CR2 |= 1<<1; // ENABLE TX DMA
    SPI1->CR1 |= 1<<6; // ENABLE SPI1

    // DMA2 CONFIG
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= 1<<22;
    DMA2_Stream3->CR |= 1<<4 | 1<<6 | 1<<8 | 1<<10 | 1<<25 | 1<<26;
}

static void sendChar(char character)
{
    GPIOA->ODR &= ~(1<<0); // CS_PIN_LOW

    DMA2_Stream3->NDTR = 1;
    DMA2_Stream3->PAR = (uint32_t) &SPI1->DR;
    DMA2_Stream3->M0AR = (uint32_t) character;
    DMA2_Stream3->CR |= 1<<0;

    while(!(DMA2->LISR & 1<<27));
    DMA2_Stream3->CR &= ~(1<<0);
    DMA2->LIFCR |= 1<<27;

//  send char without dma
//  SPI1->DR = character;
//  while(!(SPI1->SR & 1<<1));
//  while(SPI1->SR & 1<<7);
//
//  (void) SPI1->DR;
//  (void) SPI1->SR;

    GPIOA->ODR |= 1<<0; // CS_PIN_HIGH
}


"magic" numbers = "magic" results

Always debug your code by observing the related registers. If you'd do that, you'd see in DMA2_Stream3, that:
DMA2_Stream3->M0AR = (uint32_t) character;

This sets the DMA's memory pointer to the value of parameter character, not to its address. You want
DMA2_Stream3->M0AR = (uint32_t) &character;

Nonetheless, it's quite nonsensical to use DMA to transmit 1 byte. I take this to be just an exercise. In practice you'd use a pointer to array of characters as input parameter; and then indeed you could assign that pointer directly (after cast to (uint32_t)) into DMAx_StreamX->M0AR.
PS. To increase code readibility and decrease chances of mistake, use symbols from the CMSIS-mandated device header. Also, make sure your comment reflects your code, e.g. the commend says that you set PA5-PA7 to AF7, but in fact you set it to AF5.

Looking at this sample code written in registry for SPI with DMA, it seems you need to enable interrupts for DMA. your code is not much readable so try to check it yourself with the snippet code below that you do all the register configurations correctly.
/**
  * @brief  This function :
             - Enables GPIO clock
             - Configures the SPI1 pins on GPIO PA4 PA5 PA6 PA7
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
    __INLINE void Configure_GPIO_SPI1(void)
{
  /* Enable the peripheral clock of GPIOA */
  RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOAEN;
    
  /* (1) Select AF mode (10) on PA4, PA5, PA6, PA7 */
  /* (2) AF0 for SPI1 signals */
  GPIOA->MODER = (GPIOA->MODER 
                  & ~(GPIO_MODER_MODER4 | GPIO_MODER_MODER5 | \
                      GPIO_MODER_MODER6 | GPIO_MODER_MODER7))\
                  | (GPIO_MODER_MODER4_1 | GPIO_MODER_MODER5_1 |\
                     GPIO_MODER_MODER6_1 | GPIO_MODER_MODER7_1); /* (1) */
  GPIOA->AFR[0] = (GPIOA->AFR[0] & \
                   ~(GPIO_AFRL_AFRL4 | GPIO_AFRL_AFRL5 |\
                     GPIO_AFRL_AFRL6 | GPIO_AFRL_AFRL7)); /* (2) */
}

/**
  * @brief  This function configures DMA for SPI1.
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
__INLINE void Configure_DMA1_SPI1(void)
{
  /* Enable the peripheral clock DMA11 */
  RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_DMA1EN;
  
  /* DMA1 Channel3 SPI1_TX config */
  /* (5) Peripheral address */
  /* (6) Memory address */
  /* (7) Memory increment */
  /*     Memory to peripheral*/
  /*     8-bit transfer */
  DMA1_Channel3->CPAR = (uint32_t)&(SPI1->DR); /* (5) */
  DMA1_Channel3->CMAR = (uint32_t)stringtosendwSPI1; /* (6) */
  DMA1_Channel3->CCR |= DMA_CCR_MINC | DMA_CCR_DIR; /* (7) */
  
  /* Configure IT */
  /* (8) Set priority for DMA1_Channel2_3_IRQn */
  /* (9) Enable DMA1_Channel2_3_IRQn */
  NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Channel2_3_IRQn, 0); /* (8) */
  NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Channel2_3_IRQn); /* (9) */
}

Also I recommend you to use stm32cubeMX tool for code generation for a simple code to handle your task.
